# Is there some way to set just a instace of meteor publish?

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, publisher, meteor-publications

I'm trying to implement my own custom ping-pong for my meteor application (meteor has a ping-pong implemented for internal use, but I want to introduce a custom behavior). The only way that I found to send data to a client was by using a publisher, so I set a `setInterval`, to send a new payload with the timestamp of the pong, but in each new subscription is created a new `setInterval`. How could I set just a one publish or setInterval? Or there some another way to  send a message to client?

```
const COLLECTION_NAME = 'ping-pong';
const POLL_INTERVAL = 5000;

function pingPong(credentials) {
  const pongSender = () => {
    const id = _.uniqueId('pong-');
    const payload = {
      message: 'pong',
      time: Date.now(),
    };
    this.added(COLLECTION_NAME, id, payload);
  };
  pongSender();
  this.ready();
  const interval = Meteor.setInterval(pongSender, POLL_INTERVAL);

  this.onStop(() => {
    Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each publication is handled separately, but you can create only one interval and let it update a list of publication handles:

```js
const pingPongSubscribed = [];
const pingPongIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
  pingPongSubscribed.forEach(handle => {
    // ...
    handle.added(COLLECTION_NAME, DOCUMENT_ID, payload);
  });
}, 5000);

// ...

Meteor.publish('example', function () {
  // ...
  pingPongSubscribed.push(this);
  this.onStop(() => {
    pingPongSubscribed.splice(pingPongSubscribed.indexOf(this), 1);
  });
});
```

If you need more data, simply keep it in the `pingPongSubscribed`. Keep in mind, that it will be synchronized in terms of connection to one server and multiple server instances are **not** synchronized.

Also, consider using `changed` instead. Each use of `added` is creating a new document in the server and client memory. This way you'll manage only one document and react to changes accordingly.